# Will I be able to embed google maps on a website that has markers without the API key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Will I be able to embed google maps on a website that has markers without the API key?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but if your website is openly accessible, you can get the API key for free.  Note that this includes having different levels of access for different people.

Exception: You can embed all you want on localhost, to facilitate development.

Comment: @larsc, i was able to embed the map using the iframe code which we get from the google map,but it didnt have any markers on it.i just wanted to show the exact position of the location on the map,the iframe wud have done the job for me but it didnt have that red marker... any suggestions? or do i have to get the API key like you said...the only problem is the site is not online yet,its still under development..

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the Google Maps API doesn't require API keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.map-generator.net/

They use google maps...and put in a marker for you. Easy to use